# error trying to delete softlayer DNS entry

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Now that I have the add dns A record working, I am trying to delete the resource Record in SoftLayer DNS.

I issue the URL:

`https://aoi.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/getByDomainName/<my domain name>.json?objectMask=mask[resourceRecordCount;resourceRecords]`

I loop through the resource records looking to the host name to delete to get the resource record `ID`.

I issue URL:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/deleteObject/<resource record id>.json
```

I am getting:

> RC 404, MSG "not found", content "{"error":"Service does not exist","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}"

`deleteObject` is defined as a method under `SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord.

Can you help.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

1. Get the resource record id

   ```
   https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/[Dns_Domain_ID]/getResourceRecords.json

   Method: GET
   ```
2. Delete Resource record

   ```
   https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/[Resource_Record_ID]/deleteObject.json

   Method: GET
   ```

Comment: I found resource record within the domain, the resource id is 62355435. I tried the URL https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/62355435/deleteObject.json I received RC 404, MSG "not found" content '{"error":"Service does not exist","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}'

Comment: The URL was 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/62355435/deleteObject.json'

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem using `SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord::deleteObject.json` using `POST` method. Please use **GET** method and try again.

Comment: Yep, Changing DELETE method to GET method worked.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :). if it was helpful, please up-vote. Thanks